# Populating a Select with Model Data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel the need to apologize for asking such a simplistic question, but I'm getting increasingly frustrated with the Rails Guides. I'm sure they answer my question, but they don't provide enough context for me to really understand how to *apply* what they're giving me. Nor is Google much help, though I may just be searching the wrong terms/phrases. Given that disclaimer, I'm just going to go ahead and ask:

I have an `Image` that HABTM `Album`. To support that, I have an `albums_images` table with `image_id` and `album_id` fields (no others). For the life of me, I can't figure out how to populate my image form partial so that the user can select the albums a newly uploaded image should belong to.

I'm learning Rails, so I really just want the basics. I'm sure there are fancy plugins to do this a hundred ways, but I'd like to learn the basics first and build from there. My form partial is pretty much textbook:

```
<% form_for( @image, :html => { :multipart => true } ) do |f| %>
  # All the basics you'd expect to see.
<% end %>
```

My most recent attempt doesn't work any better than any other variation I've tried, but it looks like this:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :album_id %>
  <%= f.select( :album_id, current_user.albums, :id, :name ) -%>
</p>
```

Again, I recognize the simplicity of the question I'm asking and I've read what I can find, but I haven't been able to put it together into a complete solution. There seem to be many ways to do it, but no real discussion of each one, their pros/cons or how to really use them in a larger context.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** A couple of keys to note and a code correction. First, there's a HABTM relationship between images and albums. Neither model table has a FK directly referencing the other. Second, the album collection should be accessed as `current_user.albums` (corrected above). A user `has_many` albums and an album `belongs_to` user.

**UPDATE:** At the request of theIV below, at the moment, with this code:

```
22: <p>  
23:   <%= f.label :album_id %>  
24:   <%= f.select( :album_id, current_user.albums.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id]}) -%>  
25: </p>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `album_id' for #<Image:0x1042ec110>
```

I get the error in line 24.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of error you are getting? Or, post some of the output of your development log?

Comment: That's the thing, the errors are all over depending which variation I use. Often, though, there's been some sort of merge error or a missing method error for "album_id". At the moment, with this code:

    22:  <p>
    23:   <%= f.label :album_id %>
    24:   <%= f.select( :album_id, current_user.albums.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id]}) -%>
    25:  </p>

I get this error:

    undefined method `album_id' for #<Image:0x1042ec110>

I hope that helps. This is far more frustrating than I'd expected it to be.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed comments would allow code blocks. I'll add an update to the original post.

Comment: I'm assuming that the method issue is because there's no `album_id` property for images (since it's a HABTM association), but it's just the most recent. I just can't seem to find a good, comprehensive example of how to create a multiple select box from one model to populate its association with another. Or maybe I just can't find one I'm able to understand.

Comment: I think you're totally justified in asking this, the Rails API is confusing as hell!

Comment: "I'm getting increasingly frustrated with the Rails Guides. I'm sure they answer my question, but they don't provide enough context for me to really understand how to apply what they're giving me"

Nod nod x infinity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure it's the best way, the Rails way or, frankly, even an elegant way, but here's the code I've used that seems to be working so far.

```
<%= f.label 'Albums' -%>
<%= collection_select( :image, :album_ids, current_user.albums, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true } ) -%>
```

At this point, when I say "working", all I can really attest to is that the page renders with no errors and the appropriate album or albums are selected when I edit an image. I'm still shocked at how difficult it was to cobble together a "full" solution from a lot of disparate sources.

Answer (score 21):

I think that `select` elements are one of the more confusing aspects of Rails, because as you said there seem to be a number of ways to do it.

Try this:

```
<%= f.select(:album_id, @image.albums.all.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id]}) -%>
```

Comment: I've corrected/emphasized a couple of points with respect to my structure, but this didn't work for me. Could be due to changes I had to make b/c I had some bad info above. What I now have is `<%= f.select( :album_id, current_user.albums.collect { |a| [a.name, a.id] } ) -%>`. I also tried with the `.all` named_scope.